# Looking for code example to display bubble like message

Tags: android

I would like to implement a messaging interface where incoming messages is displayed inside bubble like icon.

i wonder if any body have done such code and would like to share it. I 'm only looking for example of displaying text inside bubble like image.

Comment: Do you have any examples of what you want? Maybe some code you've been working on?

Comment: I did some code for iOS that display similer buddle that shown for iPhone SMS interface. I need to port this code to Android. I can put the objective C code if you you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some useful links:

http://warting.se/2012/06/04/chat-bubbles-in-android/

http://warting.github.com/AndroidChatBubbles/

Answer (score 4):

Nothing extraordinary here. Those bubbles are just simple views with a 9 patch background image.

If you are unfamiliar with 9 patch images, spend some time on familiarizing with it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like [this](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) ?